# How to enter Array Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-js, array-formulas

Array formulas are those entered in Excel with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

With Excel API, when I read an array formula (`Range.formulas` property), I get something like `[["{=SUM(IF(A1:A10>50,1))}"]]`.

When I try to write this formula back to the worksheet, it enters a constant string (because of the brackets). If I delete the brackets and enter the formula, it will be entered as a normal formula, not as an array.

How can I enter an array formula?

---

In VBA, when you read an array formula, it returns the formula without the brackets. When you want to enter an array formula, you write `range.FormulaArray = =SUM(IF(A1:A10>50,1))` (again, without the brackets).

It would be good to keep both plataforms (JS and VBA) consistent and also provide properties like `Range.FormulaArray`, `Range.HasArray` and `Range.CurrentArray`.

Comment: Write it like `=countif(a1:a10, ">50")`

Comment: Thanks, but I used this formula only as an example. The real question is how can I enter array formulas with the Excel JavaScript API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Range.formulas` property can be used to read or set formulas for individual cells within a Range. The following code snippet populates range `C3:D5` with values (by specifying a 2-dimensional array of values)  and then sets the `Range.formulas` property (by specifying a 2-dimensional array of formulas) such that the formula in cell `D5` (i.e., the cell located in the 3rd row, 2nd column of the specified range) is `=SUM(D3,D4)`.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var rangeAddress = "C3:D5";
    var values = [["First Number", 1000], ["Second Number", 200], ["Difference", null]];
    var formulas = [[null, null], [null, null], [null, "=SUM(D3,D4)"]];
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress);
    range.values = values;
    range.formulas = formulas;
    range.load('text');

    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(range.text);
        console.log(range.formulas);
    });
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

Re adding support for the additional properties that you've mentioned, if you'd like to add this suggestion to [Office Developer Platform UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), other users can vote on it there, enabling the Office PM team to get a sense for overall priority/demand as they plan for future enhancements to the API.

---

**UPDATE**

Using the Excel JavaScript API to set an *array formula* (like you would using *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* in the UI) is not currently supported. Office Developer Platform UserVoice is the correct place to track [this feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19008853-add-array-formula-support-to-the-excel-office-add).

Comment: Thanks Kim, but array formulas are not formulas written on a worksheet array, array formulas are formulas entered with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. The suggestion link for this feature is on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19008853-add-array-formula-support-to-the-excel-office-add and I just upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Felipe, and for upvoting the feature request in UserVoice.  I've added this info to the answer, for the benefit of anyone who may not see it here in the comments. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! I think you should fix your update text to (...) is not currently supported. (...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip...I’ve fixed the typo. I suppose that’s what I get for being on Stack Overflow before I’ve had my morning coffee :)